# How to use boto3 to get a list of EBS snapshots owned by me?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have used boto3 in the past to find all images which were `not public`, so as to decrease my list of returned images from the thousands to a manageable number.

However, I can not work out how to filter EBS snapshots in this fashion.
I have tried the following

```
ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=self)
```

However, OwnerIds only takes a list of Ids.

I have been reading the following documentation: [describe_snapshots](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots), and it states that

> The results can include the AWS account IDs of the specified owners,
>   amazon for snapshots owned by Amazon, or self for snapshots that you
>   own

but I can not work out where this `self` is meant to go.
Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])
```

or you can specify your account number/id:

```
client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['123456736123'])
```

Both are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed.